# Setting the value of an input within an html string returned via ajax

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there was a way to set the value of an input (returned via an ajax call) before appending it to the document.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        var numRows = $('.row').length;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                // find input id in html that contains Order ?
                // set value of the input to numRows + 1 ?

                // append updated html to an element called #rows
                $("#rows").append(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks for any help

Here's what the html might look like

```
<div class="row">
<input type="hidden" name="OfficialAddresses.index" autocomplete="off" value="1cffe209-44e1-44ca-a013-a808bff8a174">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Address</legend>  
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="text-box single-line" id="OfficialOfficialAddresses_1cffe209-44e1-44ca-a013-a808bff8a174__Order" name="OfficialOfficialAddresses[1cffe209-44e1-44ca-a013-a808bff8a174].Order" type="text" value="0">

            </div>
            <div class="clear">&amp;nsbp;</div>
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
            <div class="clear">&amp;nsbp;</div>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us a sample of the returned html so we can give you an answer.

Comment: BTW, if the ID always ends with `Order` you can use the jQuery [`attribute-ends-width-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/). `$html.find('input[id$=Order]')`

Comment: Thanks matt! I didn't know that could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input's ID is `Order`:

```
success: function (html) {
    var $html = $(html);

    $html
        .find('#Order')        // find input id in html that contains Order
        .val(numRows + 1);     // set value of the input to numRows + 1

     // append updated html to an element called #rows
    $("#rows").append($html);
}
```

If you really mean that the input's ID only *contains* order, use a [fancier selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$html.find('input[id*=Order]').val(numRows + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes there is. If you put the returned content into a jQuery object, then you can perform selections on elements contained within and set the value.

e.g.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {

                var htmlToAppend = $(html);

                // do your searching and value setting here

                // append updated html to an elemen called #rows
                $("#rows").append(html);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        var numRows = $('.row').length;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#Order', html).val(numRows+1);

                // append updated html to an elemen called #rows
                $("#rows").append(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

whell, a workaround could be to insert the new html in a hidden div, then find the "order ?" input and set the value to wathever you want